# add our own function to when something is added to a Vuejs data element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a fairly simple Vuejs app and am just learning Vuejs. When I add or delete from a data property, I'd like some other function to happen. The code is like this:

```
data: {
  pricings: null,
},
mounted(){
  var somePrice = {"name":"service price", "price":"2.45"}
  this.pricings.push(somePrice);

}, 
methods:{
  callMe: function(){
     alert("call me");
  }
}
```

I'd like when I add or delete from pricings for some other method (`callMe` in this case) to be called. I am sure this is possible but am not having luck finding how to do it.

Comment: Usually you'd do this in a computed property: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties  (A computed function based on the value of `data.pricings` would run whenever `pricings` changes)

Comment: like @DanielBeck mentions it can be done through a computed property. It is also possible by using a watcher: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Comment: thx - looking into watcher first as I'm trying to hack some interaction between our jQuery part and Vue part. thx for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use either a [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) or a [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) property. It really depends on what your use case is.

Take the following example:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    pricings: [],
  },
  mounted() {
    const somePrices = [{
      "name": "Service",
      "price": "2.45"
    }, {
      "name": "Another Service",
      "price": "5.25"
    }, {
      "name": "Service Three",
      "price": "1.52"
    }];

    this.pricings.push(...somePrices);

  },
  methods: {
    callMe: function(newVal) {
      // console.log(newVal);
      // async or expensive operation ...
      console.log("call me");
    }
  },
  computed: {
    pricingsSum: function() {
      return this.pricings.reduce((sum, item) => sum + Number.parseFloat(item.price), 0);
    }
  },
  watch: {
    pricings: function(newVal) {
      this.callMe(newVal);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.3/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in pricings" :key="item.name">
      {{ item.name }} ${{ item.price }}</li>
  </ul>
  <p>Total: ${{ pricingsSum }}</p>
</div>
```

We used a computed property for complex logic that would prevent the template  from being simple and declarative by doing something like:

```
  <p>Total: ${{ this.pricings.reduce((sum, item) => sum + Number.parseFloat(item.price), 0) }}</p>
```

That would look even worse if you needed to repeat this operation in several parts of your template.

---

On the other hand, we used a watch property for `pricings`, which reacts to data changes for `pricings`.

Quoting the docs:

> This is most useful when you want to perform asynchronous or expensive
> operations in response to changing data.

Meaning that here you would probably make an asynchronous request to your server or some other complex/expensive operation instead of just manipulating the data like we did with our computed property.

Hope this helps, I recommend reading the full documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

---

At the end of the day a computed property is just a watcher, you can see this here:

```
function createComputedGetter (key) {
  return function computedGetter () {
    var watcher = this._computedWatchers && this._computedWatchers[key];
    if (watcher) {
      if (watcher.dirty) {
        watcher.evaluate();
      }
      if (Dep.target) {
        watcher.depend();
      }
      return watcher.value
    }
  }
}
```

The important distinction is that computed properties are synchronous and must return a value.